# How to make true false if multiple array object has same value in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make true false if multiple array object has same value in javascript...Please help

```
let matchArray = [
    {
        "arr": [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 42, 43 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 45, 46 ],
        "matched": false
    }
]
```

**My Code**

```
const handleInputChangeForDay = (data) => {    
    const {value = '', key = 0} = data;

    setTrackArray(matchArray.map((item) => item.arr.includes(Number(key)) ? 
      {...item, matched: true} : item)
    );
}
```

**Output should be look like below**

```
let matchArray = [
    {
        "arr": [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        "matched": true
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 ],
        "matched": true
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 ],
        "matched": true
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 42, 43 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 45, 46 ],
        "matched": false
    }
]
```

As matchArray first, second, third index arr key has same value so want to make them true rest keep the false
[image: Look the below image for better understand]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dictionary. Identify how many times array values appear throughout `matchArr` by using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on the object arrays, and then creating an object with key/value pairs where the value identifies how many appearances the number makes throughout the data.
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the objects in `matchArr` and if [any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) elements appear more than once (by checking its value in the dictionary) return an updated object.

```js
const matchArr=[{arr:[19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34],matched:!1},{arr:[33,34,35,36,37],matched:!1},{arr:[36,37,38,39,40],matched:!1},{arr:[42,43],matched:!1},{arr:[45,46],matched:!1}];

// Create a dictionary of values by
const dict = matchArr

  // flattening out all the obj arrays
  .flatMap(obj => obj.arr)
  
  // and then creating an object of key/value
  // pairs where the value is the number of times
  // the number appears
  .reduce((acc, c) => {
    acc[c] ??= 0
    acc[c]++;
    return acc;
  }, {});

// `map` over the original array - find out
// if any element in its array appears more than once
// by checking the dictionary, and then return an
// updated object, otherwise return the original object
const out = matchArr.map(obj => {
  if (obj.arr.some(el => dict[el] > 1)) {
    return { ...obj, matched: true };
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: its working but if there has any short way to do the same it will better by the way thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the arrays are sorted. so the result is true,
if the last element in the first object array is  bigger or equal than the first element of the array of the second object.

```js
let matchArray = [
    {
        "arr": [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 42, 43 ],
        "matched": false
    },
    {
        "arr": [ 45, 46 ],
        "matched": false
    }
];
for(let i=0; i<Math.floor(matchArray.length/2)+1;i++){
    let firstObj = matchArray[i];
    let secondObj = matchArray[i+1];
    let firstArray = firstObj.arr;
    let secondArray = secondObj.arr;
    if(firstArray[firstArray.length-1] >= secondArray[0]){
        firstObj.matched = true;
        secondObj.matched = true;
    }
}
console.log(matchArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you explain your problem better i don't really understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Please add your question to the OP in comments and not as a solution.

Comment: Actually I want compare for all arr of matchArray and the based on matched value make the matched key true or false